# Swift SceneKit animation of several points

Tags: swift, core-animation, scenekit

I have an array of values which is a mesh angles, e.q.

```
let meshAngles = [[0,0,30], 
[0,0,70],
[0,0,90]]
```

now I want to animate this angles with mesh in loop:

```
for val in meshAngles{

rotateMesh(withData: val)
}
```

and this is a rotateMesh func:

```
func rotateMesh(withData: [a, b, c]){
        let oldTransform = mesh!.transform
        let xAngle = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(degToRad(deg: a), 1, 0, 0)
        let yAngle = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(degToRad(deg: b), 0, 1, 0)
        let zAngle = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(degToRad(deg: c), 0, 0, 1)

        var rotationMatrix = SCNMatrix4Mult(SCNMatrix4Mult(xAngle, yAngle), zAngle)
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 3
        
        //DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.02) { // Change
        mesh!.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(rotationMatrix, oldTransform)
        SCNTransaction.commit()
       // }
    }
```

question is: why code execute  only last value? I think that loop ends before first animation shows and actually I ask about how to make animation of all values in array? I think about some delay inside loop but it not works

please do not see at syntax - I just get a piece of code from my program and change it to more understandable, I mean, code works.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

needs to make sequence - it means, that can't be a transform method - it mast be a some sanction method. Than in loop makes a array of actions which run in sequence when loop ends